# No Muestra un controller con swagger UI c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

Estoy integrando Swagger en Mi proyecto web API pero no muestra el Controller donde se tienen las consultas cree otro controller de prueba pero estos si los Muestra;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo de swagger configuration lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
    /// <summary>
/// Configuracion de swagger
/// </summary>
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// OBTENEMOS EL PATH DEL ARCHIVO XML DE DOCUMENTACIÓN.
    /// </summary>

    protected static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "bin", "XMWebApiJWT.xml");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// metodo de Registro de swagger
    /// </summary>
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {

                    // DEFINIMOS LAS CARACTERÍSTICAS DEL WEB API.
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Consultas ")
                        .Description("Se requiere cálculos:")
                        .TermsOfService("Términos de servicio. Según Politicas ")
                        .Contact(x => x
                            .Name("xxxx")
                            .Url("http://servicios.com.co/WebCur-api-doc.pdf")
                            .Email("ger@mail.com"))
                        .License(x => x
                            .Name("Licencia")
                            .Url("http://servicios.com.co//ServCe/license"));

                    // HABILITAMOS EL ARCHIVO DE DOCUMENTACIÓN XML.
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());

                    c.ApiKey("Authorization")
                   .Description("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkffpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmffflxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImVINnBVdEF2RE5uZS93UUtjbTE3T1E9PSIsIlBhc3N3b3JkIjoiRHFrRWczRmF0ck5aUnhNR04rbHdLUT09IiwibmJmIjoxNTc0ODcwMTI3LCJleHAiOjE1NzQ5NTY1MjcsImlhdCI6MTU3NDg3MDEyNywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL3d3dy54bS5jb20uY28vUGFnaW5hcy9Ib21lLmFzcHgiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnhtLmNvbS5jby9hcGkvQ29uc3VsdGFzREdQIn0.yrfhnIeOOqpSsILMGO25B2dfwrkTAzAuTRF1qigfpnk")
                   .Name("Bearer")
                   .In("header");
                    // If you want the output Swagger docs to be indented properly, enable the "PrettyPrint" option.
                    //
                    c.PrettyPrint();


                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    // HABILITAMOS LA AUTENTICACIÓN JWT EN LA INTERFAZ.
                    c.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");
                });
    }
}
```

el controller que no se visualiza en el swagger UI del explorador le tengo documentacion para el xml y esta con el decorado de autentication

```
/// <summary>
/// Se requiere 
/// Comparación 
///Comparación 
/// </summary>  
[Authorize]     
public class ConsultasDGPController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// libreria para seguir seguimiento de warnings errores y eventos exitosos
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly log4net.ILog XMlog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    /// <summary>
    /// Acción Controller que llame en b
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fecha"></param>
    /// <param name="lstFronteras"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Consulta.......
```

Comment: Sin el atributo `[Authorize]` te funciona?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Pero lo necesito para que autentique, pero aun asi no muestra en el swager ui el controller ConsultasDGPController